# Need help explaining some CUDA performance results

Tags: performance, cuda, histogram

We have been experimenting with different histogramming algorithms on a CUDA GPU. Most of the results I can explain, but we noticed some really weird features of which I have no clue what is causing them.

### Kernels

The weird stuff happens in a data-parallel implementation. This means that the data is distributed over the threads. Each thread looks at a subset (ideally just 1) of the data, and adds its contribution to a histogram in global memory, which requires atomic operations.

```
__global__ void histogram1(float *data, uint *hist, uint n, float xMin, float binWidth, uin\
t nBins)
{
    uint const nThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    uint const tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    uint idx = tid;
    while (idx < n)
    {
        float x = data[idx];
        uint bin = (x - xMin) / binWidth;
        atomicAdd(hist + bin, 1);

        idx += nThreads;
    }
}
```

As a first optimization, each block first constructs a partial histogram in shared memory before doing a reduction of partial histograms to obtain the final result in global memory. The code is pretty straightforward, and I believe that it's very similar to that used in Cuda By Example.

```
__global__ void histogram2(float *data, uint *hist, uint n, 
                           float xMin, float binWidth, uint nBins)
{
    extern __shared__ uint partialHist[]; // size = nBins * sizeof(uint)                   

    uint const nThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    uint const tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    // initialize shared memory to 0                                                             
    uint idx = threadIdx.x;
    while (idx < nBins)
    {
        partialHist[idx] = 0;
        idx += blockDim.x;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    // Calculate partial histogram (in shared mem)                                               
    idx = tid;
    while (idx < n)
    {
        float x = data[idx];
        uint bin = (x - xMin) / binWidth;
        atomicAdd(partialHist + bin, 1);

        idx += nThreads;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    // Compute resulting total (global) histogram                                                
    idx = threadIdx.x;
    while (idx < nBins)
    {
        atomicAdd(hist + idx, partialHist[idx]);
        idx += blockDim.x;
    }
}
```

### Results

#### Speedup vs `n`

We benchmarked these two kernels to see how they behave as a function of `n`, which is the number of datapoints. The data was uniform randomly distributed. In the figure below, `HIST_DP_1` is the unoptimized trivial version, whereas `HIST_DP_2` is the one using shared memory to speed things up:

[image: Benchmarks of histogramming kernels, relative to CPU performance]

The timings have been taken relative to the CPU performance, and the weird stuff happens for very large datasets. The optimizing function, instead of flattening out like the unoptimized version, starts to improve again (relatively). We'd expect that for large datasets, the occupancy of our card will be near 100%, which would mean that from that point on the performance would scale linearly, like the CPU (and indeed the unoptimized blue curve).

The behavior could be due to the fact that the chance of having two threads performing an atomic operation on the same bin in shared/global memory going to zero for large data-sets, but in that case we would expect the drop to be in different places for different `nBins`. This is not what we observe, the drop is in all three panels at around 10^7 bins. What is happening here? Some complicated caching effect? Or is it something obvious that we missed?

#### Speedup vs `nBins`

To have a closer look at the behavior as a function of the number of bins, we fixed our dataset at 10^4 (10^5 in one case), and ran the algorithms for many different bin-numbers.

[image: Histogram benchmark as a function of nBins]

As a reference we also generated some non-random data. The red graph shows the results for perfectly sorted data, whereas the light-blue line corresponds to a dataset in which every value was identical (maximal congestion in the atomic operations). The question is obvious: what is the discontinuity doing there?

### System Setup

```
NVidia Tesla M2075, driver 319.37
Cuda 5.5
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 0 @ 1.80GHz
```

Thanks for your help!

### EDIT: Reproduction Case

As requested: a compiling, runnable reproduction case. The code is quite long, which is why I didn't include it in the first place. The snippet is available on [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/74867/histogram-reproduction-case/). To make your life even more easy, I'll include a little shell-script to run it for the same settings I used, and an Octave script to produce the plots.

#### Shell script

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                       
runs=100

# format: [n] [nBins] [t_cpu] [t_gpu1] [t_gpu2]                                                                                                                                                   
for nBins in 100 1000 10000
do
    for n in 10 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000 50000 100000 500000 1000000 10000000 100000000
    do
        echo -n "$n $nBins "
        ./repro $n $nBins $runs
    done
done
```

#### Octave script

```
T = load('repro.txt');

bins = unique(T(:,2));

t = cell(1, numel(bins));
for i = 1:numel(bins)
  t{i} = T(T(:,2) == bins(i), :);

  subplot(2, numel(bins), i);
  loglog(t{i}(:,1), t{i}(:,3:5))

  title(sprintf("nBins = %d", bins(i)));
  legend("cpu", "gpu1", "gpu2");

  subplot(2, numel(bins), i + numel(bins));
  loglog(t{i}(:,1), t{i}(:,4)./t{i}(:,3), ...
         t{i}(:,1), t{i}(:,5)./t{i}(:,3));

  title("relative");
  legend("gpu1/cpu", "gpu2/cpu");
end
```

### Absolute Timings

Absolute timings show that it's not the CPU slowing down. Instead, the GPU is speeding up relatively:

[image: Absolute timings]

Comment: I don't believe it will be possible to give you an informed answer without you provided some more complete code someone else could analyse and run. Could you update the question with a proper repro case?

Comment: Along with the repro, could you also so some plots of absolute, rather than relative, timings?  I can't help but notice than n~2e6 is about where the data+histogram no longer fit in L3 cache, and similarly nbins~few K is when the histogram starts having trouble fitting into L1d cache.  So I'm wondering if the boosts you're seeing are less the GPU code doing well and more the CPU code doing poorly.

Comment: The discontinuity seems to appear when the size of the shared memory is `1024*sizeof(uint)=4KB` since `nBins` is related to the size of the shared memory. Are you sure it is not a bank conflict issue?

Comment: @talonmies Done! See edit for all code on snipplr and the scripts I used to generate the figures (well, modified to your convenience of course).

Comment: @JonathanDursi Absolute timings show that the CPU is just continuing linearly. It's really the GPU that is speeding up relative to the CPU... See my edit for repro and additional timings.

Comment: @JackOLantern I'm not that familiar with the hardware specifics, but I was under the impression that more bins would lead to less bank conflicts because it becomes less likely that different threads have to write to the same bin. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure you are right. Consider the initialization of the shared memory, which is done by the instruction `partialHist[idx] = 0;`. You are launching a number of `512` threads, as it emerges from the  code externally linked to. In this case, `idx` is advanced any time by `512`, so no bank conflict occurs. However, consider the calculation of the partial histograms done by the instruction `atomicAdd(partialHist + bin, 1);`. The offset `bin` depends on the data, so it is random. Consequently, each thread is randomly accessing the shared memory and I expect you do have bank conflicts.

Comment: @JackOLantern You are right about the random access of shared memory and I'm sure bank conflicts will occur. However, we would expect these to decrease as the number of bins increases, don't we? The odds of two datapoints to be in the same bin decreases when the bin-width is decreasing. This effect is visible in the sorted data.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you are saying is right. Shared memory is organized in consecutive banks of `4` bytes. A shared memory of `1024` `uint`s will contain `32` banks of `32` bytes each, since `1024 = 32 x 32`. Since the data are uniformly distributed, then the probability to access a word of `4` bytes in shared memory is also uniform. So, I would expect that bank conflict will become more serious when `nBins` increases. Anyway, have you tried to profile your code by the Visual Profiler?  Have you taken a look at the shared memory efficiency for different values of `nBins`?

Comment: @JackOLantern Interesting... will look into that. And no, no Visual Profiler here. I'm assuming that's a Visual Studio tool? I'm on Linux so I'll see what nvprof can tell me about this. Haven't used it before...

Comment: I acknowledge that my argumentation seems to justify a smooth increase in the bank conflict issue, but not the sharp discontinuity in the performance you are observing. Accordingly, it would be worth doing a profiling by nvprof if you are under linux.

Comment: @JackOLantern I've checked with `nvprof`, and the number of bank conflicts (`l1_shared_bank_conflict`) does not increase dramatically in the region where the discontinuity occurs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding **question 1**:

> This is not what we observe, the drop is in all three panels at around 10^7 bins. What is happening here? Some complicated caching effect? Or is it something obvious that we missed?

This drop is due to the limit you've set on the maximum number of blocks (1<<14 == 16384). At n=10^7 gpuBench2 the limit has kicked in, and each thread starts processing multiple elements. At n=10^8 each thread works on 12 (sometimes 11) elements. If you remove this cap you can see that your performance continues to flatline.

Why is this faster? Multiple elements per thread allows for latency of the load from data to be hidden much better, especially in the case with 10000 bins where you are only able to fit one block on to each SM due to the high shared memory usage. In this case, every element in the block will reach the global load at around the same time, and none will be able to continue until it has completed its load. By having multiple elements we can pipeline these loads, getting many elements per thread for the latency of one.

(You don't see this in gupBench1 as it is not latency bound, but bandwidth bound to L2. You can see this very quickly if you import the output of nvprof into the visual profiler)

Regarding **question 2**:

> The question is obvious: what is the discontinuity doing there?

I don't have a Fermi to hand, and I can't reproduce this on my Kepler, so I'd assume it's something that is Fermi specific. That's the danger of answering questions with two parts, I suppose!

Comment: Thanks so much for all the effort! Great answer :-)